# Parsing XML to text file using python

Tags: python-3.x, parsing, beautifulsoup, elementtree

I have a source section in an XML from which I am trying to fetch the values in this way to a text file.

source1, ipset-1, IPSet, true

source2, ipset-2, IPSet, true

XML section:

```
<sources excluded="false">
    <source>
        <name>source1</name>
        <value>ipset-1</value>
        <type>IPSet</type>
        <isValid>true</isValid>
    </source>
    <source>
        <name>source2</name>
        <value>ipset-2</value>
        <type>IPSet</type>
        <isValid>true</isValid>
    </source>
</sources>
```

Currently, my code gives me everything in one line.

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
tree = ET.fromstring(xml_file)
for node in tree.iter('source'):
    print('\n')
    with open("source.txt", "a") as file:
        for elem in node.iter():
            if not elem.tag==node.tag:
                file.write("{},".format(elem.text))
                print("{}: {}".format(elem.tag, elem.text))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A solution using `beautifulsoup`:

```py
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

xml_doc = """
<sources excluded="false">
    <source>
        <name>source1</name>
        <value>ipset-1</value>
        <type>IPSet</type>
        <isValid>true</isValid>
    </source>
    <source>
        <name>source2</name>
        <value>ipset-2</value>
        <type>IPSet</type>
        <isValid>true</isValid>
    </source>
</sources>
"""

soup = BeautifulSoup(xml_doc, "lxml")

with open("source.txt", "w") as f_out:
    for tag in soup.select("source"):
        print(",".join(t.text for t in tag.select("*")), file=f_out)
```

Creates `source.txt`:

```
source1,ipset-1,IPSet,true
source2,ipset-2,IPSet,true
```